# Remove white spaces in a large image with small colored zones

Tags: python, algorithm, plot

I have a plot with very large empty spaces. When I try to save it with `savefig()`, my colored zones are shown with small points, Like the image below:

[image: saved image using <code>savefig()</code>]

but if I zoom on `show()` output, I can see the rectangles plotted:
(almost x100 )

[image: manually zoomed output of <code>show()</code>]

The values on each axis are like:

```
x = [[start0,end0],[start1,end1],singlePoint1,...,[startn,endn],singlePoint2]
y = [[start0,end0],[start1,end1],singlePoint1,...,[startn,endn],singlePoint2]
```

and there is a list of valid areas:

```
valid = [[s0,e0], [s1,e1],SP1,...,[sn,en],SP2,... ]
```

which `x` and `y` are subsets of it.

how can I reduce the empty spaces and get something like the zoomed image (to be human-detectable!).

ANY help is appreciated

**Edit:** 
I had an idea of removing invalid areas (zones not in the `valid` list), but do not know how to do that.
Empty spaces in valid areas are more of a concern than invalid white spaces.

Comment: Are you asking how to remove the whitespace and have several breaks in the x/y-axes? If so I would suggest making 6 or 8 plots side-by-side so that it's clear to the reader at first glance what you've done. having a break in your axes anywhere other than the origin, especially having multiple of them is very misleading, if not outright deceptive.

Comment: I'm afraid it needs a hundred subplots if I want to draw them side by side. 
and there exists a list for valid areas,  maybe I should mention that.

Comment: If you have a hundred regions of interest, how do you have enough screen space for this anyway?

Comment: That's why I want to remove invalid white spaces. Then valid areas would be joined (although I'd rather an edge between joined parts or different colors) and empty spaces in the valid zones are much more noticeable.

Comment: is my question vague? I'd edit it if it needs any clarifications

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is very non-standard, so I'd be surprised if the functionality existed in matplotlib.

If you have a list of regions of interest then you could try

```
for x0,y0,x1,y1 in valid_zones:
    plt.axis([x0, x1, y0, y1])
    plt.saveFig()
```

This give you one png per valid zone, all zoomed in, with axes on them and everything. If I'm understanding your problem, you then want to combine these all into a single image by shoving them all side-by-side into some sort of grid. This you can do using an image manipulation tool, myself I like [PIL](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/pil-index.htm). You already know how many valid zones you have, let's say it's 100, and when you load back in one of these png's you can tell what their [height, width] is. So now make a giant empty image which is [10*height, 10*width], then loop through all the image files and copy them block-by-block into the big empty image. This will give you a grid of your valid zones, each with its own axes, and if you're clever with the order they'll even be in roughly the right cartesian place. If I'm understanding your question right, this is almost the same as removing the white space.

[Note]: As I said in a comment above, if this if just for your eyes, then cool, but if you're planning to put this in a report / paper then be aware that this is *really* misleading and scientifically questionable.

Comment: be sure it's not gonna be used in a misleading report :)
I am exactly searching for empty areas in valid zones. The problem is the valid zones are a small part of the whole plane.